# Exibir mensagem para validação de um formulário ao invés de alerta

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um formulário que se o usuário deixar o campo nome em branco, exibir a mensagem no campo, ao invés de um alerta. O `document.write` não funciona com função através de um evento. Estou usando `innerHTML` e `textContent`. Entretanto não consigo exibir a mensagem. Fiz dois códigos, vejamos:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script>

        function validar() {

            if (document.formulario.nome.value.length == 0) {
                var alerta = "O nome deve ser informado";
                var aviso.innerHTML = alerta;
            }
        }

    </script>

    <form name="formulario">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="cadastro" onclick="validar()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Segundo código:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function validar() {

            if (document.formulario.nome.value.length == 0) {
                var alerta = document.getElementById('alerta');
                alerta.textContent = "O nome deve ser informado";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <form name="formulario">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"> <input type="submit"
            value="Enviar" name="cadastro" onclick="validar()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No seu primeiro exemplo você está fazendo um `innetHTML` em uma variável `aviso`. Em que local você usa essa variável?

Comment: @Pedro Camara Junior  Uso a variável em <span id=aviso></span> Estou fazendo assim, sem aspas, porque vi um exemplo dum código para mostrar a hora na página no qual usava o <span> para exibir um bloco de informação pegada do innerHTML

Comment: Você precisa usar o `getElementById`, assim você não está fazendo referência alguma ao `span`. Da uma olhada na resposta que postei.

Comment: @Pedro Camara Junior por que você usa o símbolo de '$'?

Comment: É somente uma [boa prática](http://opensource.locaweb.com.br/locawebstyle-v2/manual/praticas-padroes/javascript/), para diferenciar as variáveis de elementos das demais. Funcionará da mesma maneira sem o cifrão.

Comment: @Pedro Camara Junior Eu execultei o seu código na própria resposta e funcionou. Copiei, colei na minha IDE, mas não funcionou. Mudei algumas coisas e não funcionou. Segue no jsfidle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hkoe6zm0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é criar uma div logo após o `txt` ou em um local de sua preferência, e nessa div você irá fazer o `innerHTML` da mensagem de validação, fiz um exemplo pra você ver como funciona:

```js
document.getElementById("btnEnviar").addEventListener("click", validar, false);

function validar() {
  var $divMensagem = document.getElementById('divMensagem');
  var $txtNome = document.getElementById('txtNome');

  if ($txtNome.value.length == 0)
    $divMensagem.innerHTML = 'O nome deve ser informado';
  else
    $divMensagem.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
Nome:
<input type="text" name="nome" id="txtNome">
<div id="divMensagem"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar" name="cadastro">
```